I applied for production of android app but app isn't ready for production yet why
Apply for production on 26 May after 12 hours got an email your app  is not ready for production yet. Again run your closed test for 14 days more.

Uploading new releases during testing and also give proper give reply to each tester's feedback.

Due to new google policy put app in Closed Testing with 20 Testers for 14 Consecutive Days to Publish App. Read more information here - https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/14151465?sjid=6088444920055105975-AP

i knew that.. the problem is that my app successfully completed 20 testers but after 14 days it shows that your app isn't ready for production yet

Its always nice to edit your question and share updated information with screenshot to explain your problem in better way, so that someone else might help you and stop you from getting downvotes in question.

now check image is attached in question

now check image is attached in question

Same thing happened to me. Don't know the reason why they did this. Is your app published now @contactme?
